# wordpress url category with subcategory

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

Is it possible to generate these URL's with Wordpress Categories and Subcategories:

The are two main-categories: BOY and GIRL and every main-categories have the same sub-categories:

Boys > Shoes | Jeans | Jackets
Girls > Shoes | Jeans | Jackets

If I click on Boys > shoes
the url should be: `domain.com/boys/shoes/`
but it's only `domain.com/shoes/`

What I need for is a dynamic-permalink-structure. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit the category parameter from permalink options.

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: Alright. Now you need to alter the post type. Use register_post_type and set parameter 'hierarchical' to 'true'. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: hm, no sorry but it should be domain.com/(gender)/catergory/

Comment: Hi Ash, are you using it for blog puropose ? or woocomerce ? as you are talking about shoes etc... Because i can't get sub-category and sub-sub-category in my urls with woocommerce products.

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* 

Step-1: Copy and paste in your functions.php file
Step-2: The permalinks are set as like /%category%/%postname%/

*/

Example Output: site.com/source/books/*postname* 

function hierarchy_permalink_categories($cat,$categories,$post ) {

    $arr_order = array();
    foreach( $categories as $cats_key => $current_value) {
        $arr_order[$current_value->parent] = $cats_key;
    }

    $num_order = array();
    $i = 0;

    while(!empty($arr_order[$i])){
        array_push( $num_order, $categories[$arr_order[$i]]);
        $i = $categories[$arr_order[$i]]->term_id;
    }

    return end($categories);
}

add_filter('post_link_category','hierarchy_permalink_categories', 20, 3 );
```